# jQuery send data to node.js controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

How can I render a view with the data received from client-side?

This is my `js` code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var user,pass;
    $("#submit_update").click(function(){
      user= $("#user_upd").text();
      email= $("#email_upd").text();
      $.get("/user/profile/update", {user: user,email: email}, function(data){ });
    });
  });
```

This is my Controller that is called with `/user/profile/update` url:

```
module.exports.userUpdateGet = function(req, res) {
  console.log("Controller reached");
  res.render('user_profile_update', {
    usename: req.query.user,
    email: req.query.email,
    user: req.user.username
  });
}
```

This is my route:

```
// GET user profile update
router.get('/user/profile/update', userCtrl.userUpdateGet);
```

It successfully logs `Controller reached` to console, but it doesn't render the view...

Comment: Have you tested this without AJAX yet? As in, opening `http://localhost/user/profile/update?user=abc&email=def@ghi.com` in your browser?

Comment: It doesn't work...should I also change my route? (Updated my question)

Comment: Nevermind, you aren't telling it to do anything with the response. You need to actually display the result in your `function(data){ }`. As in `$("#main").html(data);` or similar.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a useless problem description. What happens, exactly?

Comment: Sorry, using this url `http://localhost/user/profile/update?user=abc&email=def@ghi.‌​com` I receive `This site can't be reached` in the browser

Comment: Is your node server actually running on port 80...? Because you might have to go to `localhost:3000/user/...` or whatever you have in your address bar. Still, I have already identified the likely cause: you are calling `$.get()` but not doing *anything* with the result.

Comment: Forgot to specify the port ... now that address is working and my view is rendered

Comment: Ok. Now look at my second comment again.